# Where should store css file in virtualmin laravel

Tags: laravel-5, virtualmin

My `css` file is not working. I store my `css` file `public_html/css/main.css`.
But it's not working.
Where should i put this?

Comment: whats the error message ?

Comment: You need to call your css inside `<head>` tag and specify the path. Maybe you can put the css inside `public/css` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your css inside `<head>` tag and specify the path. Maybe you can put the css inside `public/css` directory. Your link should look like below:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in your index.html file for the line:

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FILENAME.css">
</head>
```

The href is the link to the .css file. Make sure the path is correct.